# $\beta_{q}=\dim H_{q}(X,\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let's define $\beta_{q}$ to be *$q^{th}$-Betti number* of X, i.e. the rank of of $H_{q}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, the $q^{th}$-homology of $X$.

How can I see that $\beta_{q}=\dim H_{q}(X,\mathbb{Q})$, where $H_{q}(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks you!

Comment: Assuming the homology is finitely generated, use the universal coefficient theorem for homology.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of this result...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Statement_of_the_homology_case

Comment: Sorry to disturb you Qiaochu. But let $\mathcal{H}$ be $H_{q}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ modulo torsion. Isn't $\mathcal{H}$ isomorphic to $H_{q}(X;\mathbb{Q})$ just mapping, say $[z]+T\in\mathcal{H}$ to $[z]\in H_{q}(X;\mathbb{Q})$. If so, then it is not hard to check that a basis for $\mathcal{H}$ is a basis for $H_{q}(X;\mathbb{Q})$ (I mean, the elements with the isomorphism applied)

Comment: No. The first thing is a bunch of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, but the second thing is a bunch of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. But universal coefficients tells you the correct thing, which is that $H_q(X, \mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $H_q(X, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.